# How do you achieve a physically sorted table file organization?

Tags: mysql

Do I just declare an Index on a column in the schema like ?

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `index_name` (`colDate`)
```

I want the table records to be physically sorted not just when doing an orderBy query.

I believe it would be best practice to index on a date if I will be consistently query a range of dates or any query regarding a sequential range. Am I correct in believing this?

Comment: Why do you want to sort the tables?

Comment: I want it to handle queries that request a range of dates quickly. I'm also researching different file orgs and it seems sorted files are best for this type of query so I'm experimenting with the different types. I just don't know how to achieve this physically sorted structure

Comment: Are you sorting the data in the tables, or the tables themselves?  Adding an index for the columns you want to sort will speed certain queries (such as `SELECT`) but slow others (such as `UPDATE`).  If performance for huge numbers of records over multiple machines is required, you should consider a NoSQL solution.